# Expo: How to fix web push notification in development when accessing through localhost (and how to fix the `localhost` service worker)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, service-worker, web-push

I am using [Expo SDK Version: 36](https://expo.io/) to generate a PWA.

- `curl http://$LOCAL_IP:19006/expo-service-worker.js`: OK 200
- `curl http://localhost:19006/expo-service-worker.js`: FAIL => **Instead of serving** `expo-service-worker.js` **it serve the static asset** `index.html`.

[image]
It cause the following error in the console:

```sh
Failed to register service-worker DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:19006/') with script ('http://localhost:19006/expo-service-worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```

The file `expo-service-worker.js` is not served and this is problematic when you must implement web push notification because only `localhost` can work without it when site is not served with `HTTPS`.

Related issues:

- https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2063
- https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2468

How can I fix it?